# Axios post multipart with object

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, axios

Here is my `spring boot` endpoint to post `file` and `object` in one request

```
@PostMapping(
    value = ["/add"],
    consumes = [
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
    ]
)
fun addUser(
    @RequestPart("user") user: UserDTO,
    @RequestPart("file") file: MultipartFile,
): Long = userService.addUser(user, file)
```

And it works perfect when I use `postman` like this:
[image]

How can I achieve exactly the same configuration with `axios`. I tried many solutions and everytime I get an error like this:

```
 org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

or this:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Here is my `axios` request

```
 const file = new FormData()
 file.append('file', photo, photo.name)

     const response = await axios.post(
        '/user/add',
        JSON.stringify({
            user,
            file
       }),
          {
            withCredentials: true,
          }
    )
```

I also tried this:

```
 const file = new FormData()
 file.append('file', photo, photo.name)

     const response = await axios.post(
        '/user/add',
        {
            user,
            file
       },
          {
            withCredentials: true,
          }
    )
```

I also tried setting the `content-type` to `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set content-type you have to pass file-like object.
It can be done using Blob.
for eg.

```
const user ={
  username: "user123"
};
const json = JSON.stringify(user);
const blob = new Blob([json],{
  type: 'application/json'
});

const body = new FormData();
body.append("user" ,blob);
body.append("file" ,photo);

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/add',
  data: body,
});
```

Comment: works perfect, thanks a lot. I would never thought about the solution like this